# How to implement a function that accepts any container type?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to implement a function that takes `std::vector` or `std::array` as an argument. How can the parameter list abstract from the container type?

See this example:

```
// how to implement this?
bool checkUniformity(container_type container)
{
    for(size_t i = 1; i < container.size(); i++)
    {
        const auto& o1 = container[i-1];
        const auto& o2 = container[i];

        if(!o1.isUniform(o2))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

struct Foo
{
    bool isUniform(const Foo& other);
}

// I want to call it in both ways:
std::vector<Foo> vec;
std::array<Foo> arr;

bool b1 = checkUniformity(vec);
bool b2 = checkUniformity(arr);
```

What is the best and most readable way to do this?

Any suggestions for code improvement (style, design) are welcome as well. Thanks!

Comment: You want to use iterators. Write a function template that works on e.g. input iterators, then pass `vec.cbegin()` and `vec.cend()` or `arr.cbegin()` and `arr.cend()` to this function. Or use what's already in the STL, e.g. [std::adjacent_find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) with a custom lambda (C++17).

Comment: @lubgr `std::mem_fn(&Foo::isUniform)` is shorter than a lambda. (`adjacent_find` isn't new in C++17, just the parallel overload)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use iterators and ranges instead of working with the container directly, you can produce an algorithm that works with any container (including linked lists) efficiently and also with streams:

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
bool checkUniformity(T begin, T end) {
    // Check for empty range
    if (begin == end) return true;

    // Remember last element
    T last = begin;
    while (++begin != end) {
        if (!((*last).isUniform(*begin)))
            return false;
        last = begin;
    }

    return true;
}

template <typename T, typename F>
bool checkUniformity(T begin, T end, F pred) {
    // Check for empty range
    if (begin == end) return true;

    // Remember last element
    T last = begin;
    while (++begin != end) {
        if (!pred(*last, *begin))
            return false;
        last = begin;
    }

    return true;
}

struct Foo
{
    bool isUniform(const Foo& other) const;
};


int main () {
    // I want to call it in both ways:
    std::vector<Foo> vec;
    std::array<Foo, 3> arr;
    std::list<Foo> list;
    Foo carr [3];

    bool b1 = checkUniformity(std::cbegin(vec), std::cend(vec));
    bool b2 = checkUniformity(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr));
    bool b3 = checkUniformity(std::cbegin(list), std::cend(list));
    bool b4 = checkUniformity(std::cbegin(carr), std::cend(carr));

    bool b1_2 = checkUniformity(std::cbegin(vec), std::cend(vec), [] (const Foo& a, const Foo& b) { return a.isUniform(b); });
    bool b2_2 = checkUniformity(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr), [] (const Foo& a, const Foo& b) { return a.isUniform(b); });
    bool b3_2 = checkUniformity(std::cbegin(list), std::cend(list), [] (const Foo& a, const Foo& b) { return a.isUniform(b); });
    bool b4_2 = checkUniformity(std::cbegin(carr), std::cend(carr), [] (const Foo& a, const Foo& b) { return a.isUniform(b); });
}
```

You can also implement a second variant as shown, where you can specify the condition as a predicate (e.g. a lambda, as shown) in case you have different variants of `isUniform`. Having to pass two parameters for the range instead of just the container is slightly more cumbersome, but much more flexible; it also allows you to run the algorithm on a sub-range of the container.

This is the same approach as used by standard-library algorithms, such as `std::find`.

Comment: Why `(*last).isUniform` and not `last->isUniform`?

Comment: Some iterator might not implement `->` as it is a convenience wrapper. However, as the [standard concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) requires the presence of `->`, this is not really necessary. So `->` would be just as good.

Comment: @Erlkoenig **You do not need two template-overloads**. Provide a default Compare-functor or lambda to the second overload and you have the for first template function by default free. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/GZ1Oie

Comment: Depends on the scope. If there is no reasonable default among multiple variants, or the algorithm should be implemented as a general utility independent of `Foo`, then a default makes little sense. Implementing both functions as exactly as shown is somewhat redundant indeed.

Answer (score 6):

You want `template`:

```
template <typename container_type>
bool checkUniformity(const container_type& container)
{
    for(size_t i = 1; i < container.size(); i++)
    {
        const auto& o1 = container[i-1];
        const auto& o2 = container[i];

        if(!o1.isUniform(o2))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that was my first thought, too. But how can I make sure, that the container has elements of type `Foo`, or more specifically, implements `isUniform()`?

Comment: If it doesn't you will have compile time error. You might still SFINAE to discard that method from overload for wrong types (You would have also compile time errors, but with different messages).

Answer (score 5):

To accept almost any container type is a good idea to use templates with template template parameters. Most of the containers in C++ accept as the fist template parameter the value type that they hold, and an allocator type, which is used to allocate memory.

To check wether the value type of the container implements a certain method, `isUniform()` in you case, you can use `std::enable_if`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo
{
    bool isUniform(const Foo&) const { return true; }
};

//Template template parameter TContainer, that accepts 2 template parameters
//the first for the value_type, the second for the allocator type
template <template <typename, typename> typename TContainer, typename TValue, typename TAllocator>
auto checkUniformity(TContainer<TValue, TAllocator>& container)
//Using `std::enable_if` to check if the result of invoking the `isUniform()` method is bool
//in case it is not bool, or the method does not exist, the `std::enable_if_t` will result
//in an error
-> std::enable_if_t
<
    std::is_same_v
    <
        decltype(std::declval<TValue>().isUniform(std::declval<TValue>())), 
        bool
    >, 
    bool
>
{
    for(size_t i = 1; i < container.size(); i++)
    {
        const auto& o1 = container[i-1];
        const auto& o2 = container[i];

        if(!o1.isUniform(o2))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> vec(10);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << checkUniformity(vec);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `std::array` does not have an allocator type, so this method will not work with `std::array`.
For that you may change `TContainer` to a simple template type parameter, and use `typename TContainer::value_type` wherever you would use `TValue`.

Comment: That's one thing I don't like about c++: even if I understand it right now, those monstrous template constructs make a hard time for my future self and colleagues reading the code later.
This might be the correct c++ approach, though.

Comment: @Sparkofska Luckily the C++ standardization cometee is aware of the ugliness of the templates, and starting from C++20 you can use `concepts` for these kind of things, with a nicer syntax and improved compile times.